# What do modern evangelicals/dispensationalists believe about the general resurrection and final judgment?

Tags: resurrection, evangelicalism, dispensationalism

I grew up attending several Baptist/Church of God/Non-denominational churches growing up in the United States (we moved around a bunch). Until I was an adult and actually read the New Testament for myself, I had never even heard of the general resurrection and final judgement.

It seemed the emphasis was on your fate immediately after death and the general feeling was that God would review your entire life and judge you at that moment [chick track style](http://www.chick.com/reading/tracts/0001/0001_01.asp). There was a big emphasis on eschatology, however mainly focused on dispensationalism, in particular the rapture. Most of any discussion was about when the rapture would happen but the idea was that all Christians would be in heaven at that point and that was pretty much the end of the story.

I actually brought this up at once in a small group a few years ago, and the leader kind of made a comment implying what I was talking about was a bit unorthodox and steered the conversation in a different direction.

A few related questions:

- What do dispensationalists believe about the general resurrection and final judgement?
- Why the complete lack of interest and teaching about this topic that seems so important in the NT?
- Is this lack of interest/teaching widespread outside of evangelicals in the USA?

Comment: This is really too broad. And it seems anecdotal - it doesn't line up with my experience (which is outside the US, but I really doubt everywhere in the US is the same.)

Comment: I think the last two questions are too much for a single question. I'm also not sure if they will be well received because they feel localized. That is your impression, but is it accurate?

Comment: My opinion on those questions: I have a similar impression. I think a lot of evangelical leaders are not classically trained theologians (they didn't go to seminary) and take a good deal of their theology from the left behind series. No joke. They really do.

Comment: @curiousdannii I can't speak for everywhere, but I do have a similar impression. I live in the inland NW USA. Ace says he's in Georgia, the opposite corner.

Comment: @rhetorician Comments are not for discussion of theological or spiritual issues. Please reserve them for requests to or suggestions on improving posts.

Comment: Answers to this question are going to be—by necessity—somewhat subjective. However I would suggest that it falls in a class of subjective that we should actually be able to handle in this QnA format. I would only suggest that answerers review [What are guidelines for "Good Subjective" answers on this site?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1376) before posting!

Comment: @aceinthehole Can you provide more concrete evidence that there is a group of Christians who ignore the general resurrection?

Comment: I am a dispensationalist evangelical with experience in Southern Baptist, Anglican, Evangelical Free, United Methodist, charismatic (European) and independent Bible churches.  Laying aside the Anglican and U. Methodist experiences, the lay and professional leaders I encounter are aware of the general resurrection and final judgement as a matter of Scriptural fact from Revelation  20:11-15.  The emphasis on fate immediately after death is tied to the sense of urgency that motivates simple Gospel presentations.  Revelation is seen as a topic for the more mature believer.

Comment: I also can't think of a single one of those churches in which I have participated where the minister was not seminary trained (Missouri, Turkey, and Nebraska).  Perhaps this is a localized issue for Aceinthehole...